# How to formulate the number of comparisons in an algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, for-loop, if-statement, time-complexity, asymptotic-complexity

I'm taking lessons on interview readiness since I'm completely self-taught. My tutor wants me to express the number of comparisons in an algorithm, presumably in a formula.

The example he gave me is a counting sort, so it has three loops; two in the same scope and one nested. There are also potentially three comparisons in the nested loop.

a)
I know that in a for loop:

```
for(var i = 0; i < n; i++)
```

there will be n comparisons. 
With a nested loop:

```
for(var i = 0; i < n; i++){
    for(var y = 0; y < n; y++){}
}
```

There are n^2 comparisons.

b)
Considering two if clauses with three potential comparisons, it looks like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < n; i++){
    for(var y = 0; y < n; y++){
        if(array[y] < target_values){}
        else if(array[y] == target_values && y <i ){}
    }
}
```

At this point isn't it n * 3n for the worst case and n * 2n for a best case? 
If we add the third loop at the scope of the outer loop above, wouldn't there be n * 3n + n comparisons, worst case to this algorithm? Best case n * 2n + n?

Answer (score 1):

- The first loop: n (Every `n` repeats of the inner loop, you compare `i` against `n`).
- The second loop: n^2
- The if condition: n^2

If the else clause is always executed (i.e. all elements >= `target_values`):

- array[y] == target_values: n^2

If the else if first clause is always true (i.e. all elements == `target_values`):

- y < i: n^2

Total of `4*n^2 + n` for worst case.

For best case, all elements are smaller than `target_values`, and you have `2*n^2 + n` comparisons.

This solution assumes several things:

- no need for comparisons for &&, which is usually true
- No [loop unrolling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unrolling)